# Can't cancel an order programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

I'm usign this script to cancel an order. But adding some logs on the function that I using I can see that I have a problem with that.

```
if ($allInvoiced) {
        echo "allinvoiced";
        return false;
 }


 public function getQtyToInvoice()
{
    if ($this->isDummy()) {
        return 0;
    }

    $qty = $this->getQtyOrdered()
        - $this->getQtyInvoiced()
        - $this->getQtyCanceled();
    return max($qty, 0);
}
```

The order was generated programmatically with a chemo payment method. What's wrong here ?.